# Quick way to convert all python function parameters into a json

Tags: python, json

Let's say I have a function defined as below.

```
def func(param1, param2, param3, param4, *args, **kwargs)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get a json object as below

```
{
    "param1":param1, 
    "param2":param2, 
    "param3": param3, 
    "param4": param4, 
    "args":args, 
    "kwargs":kwargs
}
```

I understand I could manually compose this json object within the function but just wondering if there is any quick way to do this programmatically, without having to worry about changing of parameter names, add/deletion of parameters etc.

I'm also trying to avoid just using `*args` and `**kwargs` only because I still want to maintain the self-explanation benefits of using positional parameters.

Comment: Remove all the positional arguments `param1`, `param2` etc, and pass everything via `*args` or `**kwargs`.

Comment: Instead of params and kwargs, pass an arg and create a json from that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) could be an option:

```
def func(param1, param2, param3, param4, *args, **kwargs):
    return dict(locals())
```

Demo:

```
In [6]: func(1,2,3,4,5,6,foo='yes')
Out[6]:
{'param1': 1,
 'param2': 2,
 'param3': 3,
 'param4': 4,
 'args': (5, 6),
 'kwargs': {'foo': 'yes'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a dictionary without `kwargs` , try:

```
def funct1(*args):
    dc = {}
    for i,j in zip(args,range(len(args))):
        dc["param"+str(j+1)] = i
    dc['args'] = args
    return dc
```

Now calling it:

```
>>> funct1('a',20,'wow')
{'param1': 'a', 'param2': 20, 'param3': 'wow', 'args': ('a', 20, 'wow')}
```

---

With kwargs ( didn't know what was kwargs until I searched for it now lol):

```
def funct1(*args,**kwargs):
    dc = {}
    for i,j in zip(args,range(len(args))):
        dc["param"+str(j+1)] = i
    dc['args'] = args
    dc['kwargs'] = kwargs
    return dc
```